# building jupyter docker image from another jupyter docker image

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook

I am new to docker container concepts. I have a tensorflow-gpu-jupyter docker image (pulled) that I want to run as another docker image with some additional requirements to install over the original pulled image.

**EDIT -------**

The base file I am using comes from official [tensorflow repo](https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow)

So here is the head of my Dockerfile located in /home/me/docker/:

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter

COPY . .

WORKDIR .

RUN python3 -m pip install --no-cache --upgrade setuptools pip
# RUN -r requirements.txt # <-- adding seaborn & pandas

EXPOSE 8889

ENTRYPOINT ["jupyter","--ip=0.0.0.0"]
```

This is my Dockerfile. It builds correctly but when going to port 8889, it doesn't work.. How can I change properly the ENTRYPOINT command line ?
I just want my new image to run as the base image, i.e launching a jupyter notebook.

Comment: You will have to use a FROM command and pull the base image and then add what you require then run use the required command to run the image. Usually u will need to use either Entrypoint or CMD to run your container but it depends on the context and how your application looks like.

Comment: As you may guest, I don't know how to deal with the CMD and/or ENTRYPOINT command... I just want my new image to run as the base image

Comment: Will u be able to show me how ur code looks like ?

Comment: I edited my question to show what I am trying

Comment: Usually entry point or cmd will execute some file or some command this would depend on the frame work. Can you check this as this guy uses a shell script to run the application : https://hands-on.cloud/how-to-run-jupiter-keras-tensorflow-pandas-sklearn-and-matplotlib-in-docker-container/

Answer (score 0):

Yes

You would use that as the base image i.e. the 'from' and create a new image with all your other requirements

Comment: How would I do that ?

Comment: By writing a dockerfile

Comment: thank you very much for your answer ! could you please provide me tutorial on that ?

Comment: The Docker [Sample application](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/) tutorial walks through the basic steps, in the context of a Node application.